# I am new to game design & I need a basis to start

Tags: open-source, game-development

I would like to design a simple game from scratch I know very little about coding and artwork to make the games, so I was just wondering what programs do I need and where do I start.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what language (c/c++/c#/js/python/java)? what type of game (2d/3d/text)? what platform (pc/console/android/mac)?

Comment: If you know very little about coding, why should it be open-source?

Answer (score 1):

Programs like Scratch, GameSalad, GameMaker studio, and (I think) Godot can all be used to make games without coding. Similarly, Dreams is a Playstation game for building 2D or 3D games without coding. I've also heard pretty good things about Core Games.

However, my experience with game development didn't begin with any of these. I started by coding games in Javascript using a library called P5JS (this way, you can make games that anyone can play in a web browser, even on mobile devices, which is why I particularly like this option). The Coding Train YouTube channel has a plethora of excellent, easy tutorials for coding games with P5JS. If you want to eventually write code for video games, I would highly recommend starting with The Coding Train.

I would recommend trying one of the above before trying something like Unity or Unreal Engine.